# Google Fit API endless loading consent screen

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-cloud-sdk

I have the following problem.

I created a new app in Google Cloud Platform (GCP). I created a new OAuth consent screen, set it to production and created new OAuth 2.0 Client IDs under credentials for my Android app with Bundle id and sha-1.

In the app I use an SDK which access the Fitness API.

When I try to access the fitness data (step count), the app tries to connect to the Fitness API, the list with google accounts from my phone is shown. When I select an account, the starts to load the consent screen.

The consent screen remains empty except for the loading indicator on top.

I am a bit lost here. I don't see any errors, neither in the logs of the app, nor in GCP. The status of the consent screen is "in production". The sha-1 fingerprint is the same for production and debug.

I must be missing something, but I cannot figure out what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

the consent screen was not configured correctly in GCP. I was missing scopes, links to the website and privacy policy. After I filled out the missing information I had to let GCP verify the app.

Now the app is working.